# Request module, how to stop streaming when the browser canceled

Tags: node.js, request, streaming

I want to use my server as a proxy to stream remote file from another server.

I have two source code to do the jobs

```
http = require('http')
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var externalReq = http.request({
        hostname: "brave-download.global.ssl.fastly.net",
        path: "/releases/0.7.16/winx64/BraveSetup.exe"
    }, function(externalRes) {
        res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=File.exe");
        externalRes.pipe(res);
    });
    externalReq.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

With the code above, when I cancel download the server (my local server) will stop getting data from remote server too.

I have another source code

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=File.exe");
    request('https://brave-download.global.ssl.fastly.net/releases/0.7.16/winx64/BraveSetup.exe').pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

This source code do the same job like the one above. But when I cancel download from my browser. It won't stop getting data from remote server. It keep getting data until the download is complete.

My question is how can I make the second code stop getting data from remote server once I canceled download.

Answer (score 2):

This should listen for cancel and abort the request.

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=File.exe");
    var dl = request('https://brave-download.global.ssl.fastly.net/releases/0.7.16/winx64/BraveSetup.exe');
    dl.pipe(res);
    req.on('close', function () {
        dl.abort();
    })
}).listen(8080);
```